# Convert R objects to csv/text files

Tags: r, rdata

Has anyone tried to convert R objects to text files ? I have R objects created from Seqmeta package and am trying to convert it to text file

```
load("variant.Rdata")
write.csv(variants, file="variants.csv")
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) :
  cannot coerce class ""seqMeta"" to a data.frame
```

Then I tried

```
dump(variant, file="variant_file")
Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : invalid first argument
```

How can I convert the data to csv format ?

Comment: What is the object `variants`? This information is required. The function `write.csv` is explained by running `?write.csv` in an R session. Also if you do `str(variants)` what does it return? This tells you about the object.

Comment: Do a `str(variants)` and you'll see it is about as far from a `data.frame` (or anything else `write.csv` can process) as one can get. It's a very complex data structure (a big list [prbly] and also many nested lists and object within lists).

Comment: Yes, `str(variant)` looks very complex. So what is the more appropriate way of viewing such data. My data looks like this `>head(variant, n=1) >
$Gene1
$Gene1$scores
rs1 
        0 

$Gene1$cov
1 x 1 sparse Matrix of class "dsCMatrix"
          rs1
rs1         .

$Gene1$n
[1] 1234

$Gene1$maf
rs1 
        0 

$Gene1$sey
[1] 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to save generic R objects, you would typically use `saveRDS` (this is preferable to using `save` for a single object).  If the file must be ASCII, `saveRDS`,`save`, and `serialize` all have the parameter `ascii=TRUE`, with `serialize` producing the most readable output.

If you need the file to be human readable ASCII, you were on the right track with `dump`.  The only change you need is that `dump` takes the *name* of the object as its argument:

```
dump('variant', file="variant_file")
```

Here is an example of the sort of output from each of these options for a random neural network:

```
> serialize(model,connection = (con<-file('nn','w')),ascii = TRUE)
NULL
> close(con)
> writeLines(readLines('nn',n=10))
A
2
197122
131840
787
13
14
3
11
2  


> dump('model',file='nn2')
> writeLines(readLines('nn2',n=20))
model <-
structure(list(n = c(11, 2, 1), nunits = 15L, nconn = c(0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 12, 24, 38), conn = c(0, 1, 
2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 
10, 11, 0, 12, 13, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11), nsunits = 14, 
    decay = 0.3, entropy = FALSE, softmax = FALSE, censored = FALSE, 
    value = 198533.158122471, wts = c(19.0054841585536, 2.23487502441887, 
    4.18125434527288, -6.18031807633724, 1.74046449146894, -12.6452914163319, 
    4.36482412477615, -13.8535055297175, -2.86352652003103, -8.26639784261127, 
    -12.6981294199594, 4.6795318281078, 21.4576975495026, 2.3237431117074, 
    6.11977661730472, -4.72698798667361, -0.850474104016898, 
    -13.6710933522033, 4.09687948057462, -12.53360483838, -4.62974366307091, 
    -10.2276751641509, -11.5384259593477, 0.393593676803197, 
    11.9212104035313, -23.389751188319, 20.3888183920005, -0.900624040655219, 
    1.0351758513862, -0.343608722841881, -1.66543302778472, -1.29803652137646, 
    0.242127071364901, 0.994889406131462, -2.30836053849945, 
    0.190090309268229, -0.35494347864244, -0.201148348574871), 
    convergence = 0L), .Names = c("n", "nunits", "nconn", "conn", 
"nsunits", "decay", "entropy", "softmax", "censored", "value", 
"wts", "convergence"), class = "nnet")
```